# how to access stored image from a folder in WP

Tags: php, html, wordpress, image

I have a folder in wp directory named Punjab. i stored an image in this directory through php code as follow:

```
$target_dir = "punjab/";

$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

$uploadOk = 1;

$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        $name=$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];
        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `mydatabase`.`table` () VALUES ();") or die(mysql_error());
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
```

and the folder Punjab stored the image

but now when i want to retrieve this image through the following code:

```
$tab = array();
$dir="punjab/"; // Directory to parse

if ($dir_list = opendir($dir)) {
    while(($filename = readdir($dir_list)) !== false) {
        if($filename != ".." && $filename != ".") {
            $tab[$filename] = $dir.$filename; // Hyperlink Path
        }
    }

    closedir($dir_list);

}

foreach ($tab as $filename => $hyperlink) {
    echo '<a href="'.$hyperlink.'"><img src="'.$hyperlink.'" title="Click here to see more details"/></a><br>';
}
echo '<a href="'.$hyperlink.'"><img src="'.$hyperlink.'" title="Click here to see more details"/></a><br>';
```

not working

Comment: echo '<a href="'.$hyperlink.'"><img src="'.$hyperlink.'" title="Click here to see more details"/></a><br>'; this the last echo

Comment: what is wrong with code fomating

Comment: I meant that as a editing message and comment instead; sorry about that. I fixed the formatting. Now, maybe try clarifying why it doesn't work. An error is thrown? What happens?

Comment: @LuanNico  no error is thrown. the error log is empty. i have made a folder in wp directory with name punjab. this code is working on my custum php website but not on WP